# Uncaught Error? ó syntax error?

Tags: php, script, sintaxis

tengo el siguiente problema.
La idea es asignar valores a un atributo creado.
El atributo es una base de datos en donde previamente se cargan los atributos como tablas, y luego en este script la idea es cargar los valores de esos atributos. Por ejemplo, el atributo o tabla "color", asignarle valores de los colores blanco, negro, azul, etc.

En este programa, hago un select para elegir los atributos, y luego abajo escribir un valor para guardarlo al atributo correspondiente. Es decir, elegir el atributo color, y asignarle un valor, por ejemplo, negro.

Por lo tanto, tengo que identificar qué se elige en el select para saber qué valor asignar a cada atributo.

Lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    if(isset($_POST["atributo"]) && isset($_POST["valor"])) {
        if($_POST["atributo"]!="" && $_POST["valor"]!=""){
            include "conexion.php";

            $found = false;
            $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM \"$_POST[atributo]\" WHERE valor=\"$_POST[valor]\"";
            $query = $con->query($sql1);
            while ($r=$query->fetch_array()) {
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
            if($found){
                print "<script>alert(\"El valor ya está registrado.\");window.location='../atributos.php';</script>";
            }
            $sql = "INSERT INTO '\"$_POST[atributo]\"' (valor,created_at) VALUE (\"$_POST[valor]\",NOW())";
            $query = $con->query($sql);
            if($query!=null){
                print "<script>alert(\"Registro exitoso.\");window.location='../index.php';</script>";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

El problema que tengo es que al querer registrar la operación, me resulta el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array()
>   on boolean in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\estudiomanager.com\test\atributos\php\registroval.php:10
>   Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\estudiomanager.com\test\atributos\php\registroval.php
>   on line 10

He probado diferentes formas de escribir '\"$_POST[atributo]\"' en la parte de $sql = "INSTER INTO... y el resultado ha cambiado.

Por ejemplo, si cambio el $_POST que quiero hacer en el INSERT INTO, y lo escribo de la siguiente manera:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO '$_POST['atributo']'
```

El error es el otro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
>   expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or
>   number (T_NUM_STRING) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\estudiomanager.com\test\atributos\php\registroval.php
>   on line 17

Espero que el problema sea  simplemente un problema de sintaxis, pero no logro dar con la forma correcta de escribirlo.

Gracias a todos por leer.

Comment: Sería de mucha ayuda que agregues la estructura de tus tablas.

Comment: La tabla "color", en este caso, solo tiene id, valor (donde iría el color), y created_at.

Comment: Esto `$query = $con->query($sql1);` está retornando `FALSE` porque hay algún error en la consulta. Imprime la variable con `echo `$sql1;`  y pruébala directamente en la base de datos. Acostumbra siempre a sacar los datos del POST en variables, para escribir un código más claro y ordenado.

Comment: Antes de `$sql1` agrega las variables `$atributo = $_POST['atributo']; $valor = $_POST['valor'];` y luego en `$sql1` haces esto: `$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM '$atributo' WHERE valor = '$valor' ";`

Comment: Todavía nada, estoy trabajando con los errores de sintaxis, ya que es lo único que hasta ahora funciona, es decir, del error de la línea 10, cuando cambio las comillas o como está escrito el $_POST, el problema se va a la linea 17, diciendo que error de sintaxis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

luego de probar todas las posibilidades, seguí el consejo de A. Cedano (no se si se puede etiquetar a las personas aquí).

Básicamente, hice un `echo` de todas las consultas que terminaban en error, puesto que los errores provenían de una mala sintaxis de consulta a la base de datos MySQL.

Por lo pronto, el script quedó de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    if(isset($_POST["atributo"]) && isset($_POST["valor"])) {
        if($_POST["atributo"]!="" && $_POST["valor"]!=""){
            include "conexion.php";

            $found = false;
            $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM $_POST[atributo] WHERE valor=\"$_POST[valor]\"";
            $query = $con->query($sql1);
            while ($r=$query->fetch_array()) {
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
            if($found){
                print "<script>alert(\"El valor ya está registrado.\");window.location='../atributos.php';</script>";
            }
            $sql = "INSERT INTO $_POST[atributo] (valor,created_at) VALUE (\"$_POST[valor]\",NOW())";
            $query = $con->query($sql);
            if($query!=null){
                print "<script>alert(\"Registro exitoso.\");window.location='../index.php';</script>";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Los cambios fueron hechos en las variables `$sql1` y luego en `$sql`.
Al parecer era un simple problema de comillas mal puestas, y por lo tanto, mal interpretadas.

Gracias por las respuestas y las ayudas.

Saludos!